# Automatically paraphrasing sentences in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, is it possible to automatically replace a regular expression in a sentence with a randomly generated match of that regular expression? I'm trying to use this approach to automatically paraphrase a sentence using a list of regular expressions, like so:

`replaceWithRandomFromRegexes("You aren't a crackpot! You're a prodigy!", ["(genius|prodigy)", "(freak|loony|crackpot|crank|crazy)", "(You're |You are |Thou art )", "(aren't|ain't|are not)"])`

Here, each match of each regular expression in the input string should be replaced with a randomly generated match of the regular expression.

```
function replaceWithRandomFromRegexes(theString, theRegexes){
    //For each regex in theRegexes, replace the first match of the regex in the string with a randomly generated match of that regex.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible. I created a function called `replaceWithRandomFromRegexes` to accomplish this task.

http://jsfiddle.net/KZyZW/2/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
document.body.innerHTML += (replaceWithRandomFromRegexes("You aren't a crackpot! You're a prodigy!", ["(genius|prodigy)", "(freak|loony|crackpot|crank|crazy)", "(You're |You are |Thou art )", "(aren't|ain't|are not)"]))+"<br/>";
}

function replaceWithRandomFromRegexes(theString, theRegexes) {
    //alert(theRegexes);
    for (var i = 0; i < theRegexes.length; i++) {
        theString = globalReplaceWithRandomFromRegex(theString, theRegexes[i]);
        //alert(theRegexes[i]);
    }
    //alert("All the regexes: " + theRegexes);
    return theString;
}

function globalReplaceWithRandomFromRegex(theString, theRegexString) {
    var theRegex = new RegExp(theRegexString, "gi");
    //replace all matches of theRegex with '<thing to replace>'
    theString = theString.replace(theRegex, "<thing to replace>")


    //replace the first match of '<thing>'

    while (theString.indexOf("<thing to replace>") != -1) {
        theString = theString.replace("<thing to replace>", getRandomStringFromNestedParentheses(theRegexString));
    }

    //alert(theString);
    return theString;
}

function getRandomStringFromNestedParentheses(theString) {
    while (theString.indexOf("(") != -1) {
        theString = replaceInFirstParentheses(theString);
    }
    return theString;
}

function replaceInFirstParentheses(theString) {
    //find the index of the first parentheses
    var parenthesesIndex = theString.indexOf("(");
    var randomString = getRandomStringInsideParentheses(theString, parenthesesIndex);
    //alert(randomString);

    //theString = theString.replace();

    //find the string to replace
    var stringToReplace = theString.substring(parenthesesIndex, getCorrespondingParenthesesIndex(theString, parenthesesIndex) + 1);
    //alert(stringToReplace);
    theString = theString.replace(stringToReplace, randomString);
    //alert(theString);
    return theString;
}

function getRandomStringInsideParentheses(string, parenthesesIndex) {
    var stringArray = getStringsInsideParentheses(string, parenthesesIndex)
    //find out how to pick random in a range
    //pick something random from the array declared above
    //var theMin = 0;
    //var theMax = stringArray.length-1;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * stringArray.length);
    return stringArray[randomNumber];
}

function getStringsInsideParentheses(string, parenthesesIndex) {
    //alert("calling function getStringsInsideParentheses");
    var theString = getStringFromParentheses(string, parenthesesIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
        var theParenthesesNum = getParenthesesNum(theString, i);
        if (theString[i] == '|') {
            //alert("Parentheses num: " + theParenthesesNum);
            if (theParenthesesNum == 0) {
                theString = theString.substring(0, i) + "|" + theString.substring(i, theString.length);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    //alert(theString);
    return theString.split("||")
}

function getStringFromParentheses(theString, parenthesesIndex) {
    return theString.substring(parenthesesIndex + 1, getCorrespondingParenthesesIndex(theString, parenthesesIndex))
}

function getCorrespondingParenthesesIndex(theString, openingParenthesesIndex) {
    if (!parenthesesAreMatching(theString)) {
        writeMessage("Error: The parentheses do not match!");
        return false;
    }
    if (theString.charAt(openingParenthesesIndex) != "(") {
        writeMessage("Error: The index must be an opening parentheses!");
        return false;
    }
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = openingParenthesesIndex; i < theString.length; i++) {
        if (theString.charAt(i) == "(") {
            num++;
        }
        if (theString.charAt(i) == ")") {
            num--;
        }
        if (num == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    writeMessage("Error: The parentheses do not match!");
    return false;
}

function parenthesesAreMatching(theString) {
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
        if (theString.charAt(i) == "(") {
            num++;
        }
        if (theString.charAt(i) == ")") {
            num--;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0) {
        return i;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getParenthesesNum(theString, index) {
    //this should be based on parenthesesAreMatching, but stopping at index
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (theString.charAt(i) == "(") {
            num++;
        }
        if (theString.charAt(i) == ")") {
            num--;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

The original sentence was `You aren't a crackpot! You're a prodigy!` Here are some automatically paraphrased versions of this sentence, as produced by this script:

```
You are not a freak! Thou art a genius!
You aren't a crackpot! You're a prodigy!
You ain't a crackpot! You are a genius!
You ain't a freak! You're a prodigy!
You are not a crackpot! You are a prodigy!
You are not a loony! You're a prodigy!
You are not a loony! You are a genius!
You are not a loony! You are a prodigy!
You ain't a crackpot! Thou art a prodigy!
You are not a loony! Thou art a prodigy!
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you create a parse tree from the regex. For example: `((He|She|It|(B|R)ob(by)) (really|truly|surely) is))` becomes `concat(alt(He,She,It,concat(alt(B,R),obby),<space>,alt(really,truly,surely),<space>is)` (`concat` and `alt` can be array that contains other `concat` and `alt` arrays). With this, you can easily traverse the structure to generate random text, and support escaping (such as `\(` and `\|`)

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be much simpler than you think. How about:

```
function randomReplace(subject, groups, wordsOnly) {
    var meta = /([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, all = {};
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
        group.forEach(function(word) { all[word] = group })
    });
    var r = Object.keys(all).
        sort(function(x, y) { return y.length - x.length }).
        map(function(x) { return x.replace(meta, "\\$&") }).
        join("|");
    if(wordsOnly)
        r = "\\b(" + r + ")\\b";
    return subject.replace(new RegExp(r, "g"), function($0) {
        return all[$0][Math.floor(Math.random() * all[$0].length)]
    });
}
```

Example:

```
s = randomReplace(
    "You aren't a crackpot! You're a prodigy!",
    [
        ["genius", "prodigy"], 
        ["freak", "loony", "crackpot", "crank", "crazy"], 
        ["You're ", "You are ", "Thou art "], 
        ["aren't", "ain't", "are not"]
    ]
);
console.log(s) // You ain't a crank! Thou art a genius!
```

The expansion function, as discussed in the comments, could be like this:

```
function expand(s) {
    var d = [];

    function product(a, b) {
        var p = [];
        a.map(function(x) { b.map(function(y) { p.push(x + y) })});
        return p;
    }

    function reduce(s) {
        var m;
        if(s.indexOf("|") >= 0)
            return [].concat.apply([], s.split("|").map(reduce));
        if(m = s.match(/~(\d+)(.*)/))
            return product(reduce(d[m[1]]), reduce(m[2]));
        return [s];
    }

    function add($0, $1) { d.push($1); return '~' + (d.length - 1) }

    s = s.replace(/([^()|]+)/g, add);
    for(var r = /\(([^()]*)\)/g; s.match(r);)
        s = s.replace(r, add);

    return reduce(s);
}
```

Example:

```
z = "(He|She|It|(B|R)ob(by|)) (real|tru|sure)ly is"
console.log(expand(z))
```

Result:

```
[
 "He really is",
 "He truly is",
 "He surely is",
 "She really is",
 "She truly is",
 "She surely is",
 "It really is",
 "It truly is",
 "It surely is",
 "Bobby really is",
 "Bobby truly is",
 "Bobby surely is",
 "Bob really is",
 "Bob truly is",
 "Bob surely is",
 "Robby really is",
 "Robby truly is",
 "Robby surely is",
 "Rob really is",
 "Rob truly is",
 "Rob surely is"
]
```

Comment: @AndersonGreen: the question looks just fine to me.

Comment: I think this answer is more sane than OP's answer. Start from the different pieces of text is better than starting from the regex form.

Comment: @thg435 That depends on whether or not this solution will work properly with regexes that contain nested parentheses, and generate the random strings correctly in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to use this function to generate random strings from regular expressions that contain nested parentheses, such as `/((He|She|It|(B|R)ob(by)) (really|truly|surely) is))/`? I figured out how to do this in the solution that I posted here.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Just expand them out.

Comment: @nhahtdh Can you edit the solution to show an example of this? It isn't clear to me how the expansion should be done.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: (I am not author of this solution). For this case, expanding out would mean `"He really is", "He truly is", etc.`. Not a very good idea if the structure is so complex.

Comment: @nhahtdh In that case, my solution would probably be more effective overall - it can handle nested parentheses properly, while this solution can't (in its present state).

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I've added the expansion function to the post.

Comment: @thg435 It would probably be better to generate a single random string from a regular expression than to generate every single possible combination of the regular expression. Depending on the number of parentheses, there could potentially be millions or billions of possible combinations for a given regex.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: sure, this solution is not terribly efficient, just an example.